# Имитировать Ctrl+V через selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Нужно после открытия браузера нажать сочетание клавиш **Ctrl+V**, но окно браузера *"headless"* то есть работает в фоновом режиме. Имитировать нажатие напрямую с пк не получится - файл просто не вставится *(окно скрыто)*, нужно именно сделать это как-то при помощи **selenium**.

Comment: То есть через обычный send_keys не работает?

Comment: Может быть я не много знаю про send_keys, но когда я пробовал его использовать, он мне просто печатал "Ctrl+V". Тем более его нужно куда-то применить, на какое-то input окно, иначе выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Сейчас проверю, отпишусь.

Comment: Нашёл информацию по этой функции, оказывается вне ковычек можно дописать например `Key.CTRL`. При помощи этого можно вписывать комбинации.      Поскольку у меня сейчас нет доступа к python, не могли бы вы проверить, работает ли сочитание клавиш Ctrl+V при скопированном файле (не текст)?

Comment: Все верно. Только что проверил - send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v') - работает. Только обязательно вначале импорт from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # Необходимый класс

target_input = # Цель для копипаста
target_input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
```